# Why doesn't Windows find this shortcut?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a shortcut to a Steam game `Age of Empires II Definitive Edition` in my Misc folder, that sits on my desktop.

[image]

I've also told Indexing Options to index that folder:

[image]

So when I search for the game in the Start menu, it only finds Age of Empires II HD Edition, but not the Definitive edition:

[image]

The HD Edition shortcut has been in that folder for about a year, while Definitive Edition got placed there about a month ago.

Why can't Windows find the Definitive Edition shortcut?

Comment: Did you already try to [rebuild the search index](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-rebuild-search-index-windows-10-a.html)?

Comment: @Run5k I rebuilt the index, but still no luck.

Comment: That is rather strange.  Since it is actually an Internet shortcut rather than an application shortcut, you may want to consider copying it to the `Favorites` folder within your user profile and see if that works.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k Still don't see it.  I've just placed the shortcut in Favorites, but still nothing - maybe I have to wait for the PC to index it, but I doubt.  Btw, small correction, it's not an Internet shortcut, but rather a steam shortcut.  Like steam://rungameid/813780